# Sharepoint 2013 BCS Connectivity

Tags: bcs

I have created a BCS Service but as I am clicking on it, this is giving me error..
please tell me what is the problem and how to trace it.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the error message as plain text, it is hard to tell what it says from your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure the service is started:

> Go to Central Administration -->  Application Management --> Under Service Applications
>   Click Manage services on server. Start Business Data Connectivity service.

[Source](http://blog.milanchauhan.com/2013/05/bcs-application-throwing-there-are-no.html)

Comment: Thanks Robert :) but in "Application Management -> Manage Service Application" it was already "Start". Then what was that "Start" for. as it is in my given Image on thread.

Comment: Most services in SharePoint are constructed of two parts (the service application is one part, and a web service is the other).The service can be started but at the same time the web service can be stopped. But the service application do need the web service to function, so you have to start the web service as well